# Can´t share created pdf on Android 11

Tags: android, pdf, sdk, share, android-external-storage

I have an app, in which I want to create and share a pdf file.
I can create and share it with Android 10 (SDK Version 29) but can´t do it with Android 11 (sdk 30).
I just wanted to upload the update with sdk 29 but it wasnt possible with the google play console. It wanted min sdk 30.
I already tried it with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and it works but I can´t request for permission.
The User would have to open the settings and give the permission for this app manually. I think it´s much to complicated.
Maybe someone can help me?

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_ec_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_ec_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">
```

Build Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eclisse.eclissede"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.0.9"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        ndk{
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi", "arm64-v8a"
        }
```

ActivityClass:

```
        if (checkPermission()) {
        }else{
            requestPermission();
        }

        fabShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("size", "" + frameView.getWidth() + " " + frameView.getWidth());
                bitmap = LoadBitmap(frameView, frameView.getWidth(), frameView.getHeight());
                createPdf();

            }
        });
    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int permission1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int permission2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int permission3 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return permission1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permission2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permission3 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private Bitmap LoadBitmap(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        v.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;

}

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void createPdf() {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
          Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;

        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(convertWidth, convertHighet, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, convertWidth, convertHighet, true);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        document.finishPage(page);

        // write the document content
//        String targetPdf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Drawing";
//        File file;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "Eclisse techn. Zeichnung.pdf");
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Etwas ist schief gelaufen: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }////////////////////

        // close the document
        document.close();

        share();
//        openPdf();

    }

//    private void openPdf() {
//        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "Drawing.pdf");
//
//        if (file.exists()) {
//            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Masskonfigurator_Zeichnung.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
//            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
//            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
//            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
//            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//
//            try {
//                startActivity(intent);
//            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
//                Toast.makeText(this, "No Application for pdf view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        }
//    }



        private void share() {
        Uri uri;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "Eclisse techn. Zeichnung.pdf");
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName()+".provider",file);

        } else {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Eclisse App - Techn. Zeichnung");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Technische Zeichnung von Eclisse");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);

        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using"));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Daniel

Comment: If you can create a file under Android 11+ you can share it using FileProvider. So i do not understand your problem.

Comment: `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "Eclisse techn. Zeichnung.pdf");` Dont tell us that your app created a file there in root of external storage. Impossible under Android 11+. Use file.exists() to check existence before use.

Comment: "If you can create a file under Android 11+ you can share it using FileProvider. So i do not understand your problem." As I wrote in my question, I can share it, when the user allow permission for ALL files (not only media data). But I can request permission only for media files (not for ALL files).

Comment: @blackapps "Dont tell us that your app created a file there in root of external storage. Impossible under Android 11+. Use file.exists() to check existence before use." My App created the file under Android 11+ cause I use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE... I just wanns know, how to solve one of these two options:      1. OPTION: How to upload .abb file with SDK 29 to google play console (get the error, that i has to be min. SDK 30.      2. OPTION: How to request permission for ALL Files (not only media files).

Comment: Those are quite different questions as you have in your post and have nothing to do with the subject of your post. Please write another post that is clear and to the point as all this now is pretty confusing.

Comment: @blackapps Okay, I will write two separate posts, even I don't know how to write it even more understandable... I have a problem (I cant share the pdf) and I know that I have two Options to solve the problem. And I want to know, how to realize one of this two options... but yes I will write two posts, for each option one.